# Capturar tamanho da tela no momento da requisição

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber se existe em JavaScript alguma forma de executar métodos no momento da requisição que o cliente faz ao servidor. Tenho um projeto onde utilizo várias imagens grandes no quesito memória ocupada, e seria interessante capturar o tamanho da tela no momento da requisição pra servir a imagem com peso mais adequado ao dispositivo do usuário.

Comment: Penso que ao fazeres a requisição ao servidor tens de enviar a informação do dispositivo, para o servidor tratar a informação consoante o dispositivo.

Comment: Sim... De fato. Mas como ter acesso a esses dados? Especificamente falando, as dimensões da tela?

Comment: Penso que a resposta do @afsantos está correcta. Eu iria pelo mesmo caminho :)

Comment: Tamanho da tela não é um parâmetro enviado naturalmente na requisição HTTP, você pode criar uma extensão para o browser que insira esses valores, ou meter um cookie com esses dados.

Answer (score 14):

[Esta questão](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/how-to-get-web-page-size-browser-window-size-screen-size-in-a-cross-browser-wa) no SOen pode ser de interesse. Em particular, compilo aqui algumas das sugestões dadas.

Obter tamanhos da página e browser, com jQuery:

```js
$(window).height();   // altura do browser
$(document).height(); // altura do documento HTML
$(window).width();   // comprimento do browser
$(document).width(); // comprimento do documento HTML
```

Obter tamanho do ecrã:

```js
screen.height;
screen.width;
```

Alternativa sem jQuery:

```js
var w = window,
    d = document,
    e = d.documentElement,
    g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
    x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,
    y = w.innerHeight|| e.clientHeight|| g.clientHeight;
```

Outra forma de obter dimensões de ecrã, aparentemente suportada pelos browsers em geral:

```js
alert(window.screen.availWidth);
alert(window.screen.availHeight);
```

Testei-as na consola do browser (Firefox 27.0.1), e todas funcionam. É uma questão de ver qual é a medida que lhe interessa mais, possivelmente a da janela do browser.

Não sei se é possível enviar estes dados junto com o pedido da página. Contudo, pode optar por *carregamento lazy* das imagens, se for possível. Usaria algum elemento temporário no HTML para preencher o espaço, e dar a entender ao utilizador que ainda falta algo. E daí, manda carregar as imagens certas o mais rápido possível. Exemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
           if ((window.screen.availHeight < 1234) &&
                   (window.screen.availWidth < 1234))
               document.getElementById("img1").src = "small";
           else
               document.getElementById("img1").src = "big";
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="img1" src=""/>
    <p>Algum texto.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Alternativamente, pode dar uma olhada nas [media queries do CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/), se ajudar. Tem aqui um [artigo](http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design) que fala um pouco sobre o assunto.

Comment: Sim amigo. Suas sugestões são úteis.Mas o problema não é obter os tamanhos. É o momento em que esses tamanhos são obtidos. O máximo que consigo, é carregar essas variáveis no evento onload. Procuro uma forma de carregá-las no momento em que o browser requisita a página. Porque creio que depois que os dados são baixados, não faz sentido eu trocar as imagens. Eu teria que fazer isso durante a requisição pra diminuir o tráfego de dados. Entende?

Comment: @PedroVinícius Entendi, e juntei à resposta mais algumas sugestões.

Answer (score 3):

Bom dia amigo!

Bom, podemos dividir a sua pergunta em 2 etapas: Captura do tamanho da tela e envio para o servidor.

O amigo @afsantos respondeu corretamente como pegar o tamanho da tela:

```
var w = window,
    d = document,
    e = d.documentElement,
    g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
    x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,
    y = w.innerHeight|| e.clientHeight|| g.clientHeight;
```

Para conseguir enviar essas informações para o servidor, seria interessante o uso de ajax.
Seguindo o mesmo padrão da alternativa sem JQuery, o código ficaria da seguinte maneira:

```
var xmlhttp;

/* Requisição Ajax para o servidor */
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://servidor/pagina.php?width="+x+"&height="+y, true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
         document.getElementById("id_div").innerHTML = '<img src="' + xmlhttp.responseText + '" />'
    }
}
xmlhttp.send();
```

Neste caso, o `xmlhttp.responseText` iria ser a resposta do servidor, contendo a URL da melhor imagem para ser carregada, de acordo com os parâmetros width e height que você passou.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o seguinte para definir o `src` da imagem logo que a tag `img` for renderizada:

```
<img src="" onerror="this.src = 'http://myserver/myimage?w=' + screen.width + '&h=' + screen.height" />
```

Assim sendo, o `screen.width` e o `screen.height` serão passados como parâmetros de carregamento da imagem para o servidor, que pode então devolver a imagem do tamanho mais apropriado.

Ou então você pode fazer o processamento que achar mais devido dentro do handler do evento `error` para carregar a imagem mais apropriada.

O evento `error` é chamado pois a tag de imagem possui o src vazio a princípio... se você tentar carregar uma imagem, e então der erro no carregamento o `onerror` será chamado de novo, e assim entrará em loop. Portanto, o ideal seria limpar o evento, de forma que este seja executado apenas um única vez.

Answer (score 1):

Você pergunta sobre JavaScript, então o jeito é enviar os dados via Ajax e fazer um redirecionamento. Aí quando recarregar a página, você já vai ter os dados guardados em *session* lá no servidor (enviados pela requisição Ajax logo antes).

A sequência seria:

1. O servidor tem os dados de tamanho de tela em *session*?
2. Se sim, já manda a página na medida certa.
3. Se não, manda só um JavaScript mínimo para:

   - obter os dados e em seguida enviá-los via Ajax (e o servidor grava os dados em *session*);
   - no *callback*, `location.reload()` ou `window.location = '...'` para (re)carregar;
   - pronto - estamos de volta no ponto 1 (e a resposta será "sim").

(Se você não quer Ajax, pode até colocar os dados de tamanho de tela em *query string*.)

---

Mas se você não falasse em JavaScript, minha resposta seria puro CSS: **use `@import` condicional com *media queries***!

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

A ideia é carregar um arquivo CSS específico, de acordo com o tamanho da tela. Você pode facilmente colocar uma imagem como `background-image` de um `div` ou outro elemento (não precisa especificar URL da imagem no `img` do HTML).

Mais ou menos assim:

```
@import url('grande.css') screen and (min-width: 1080px);
@import url('medio.css') screen and (min-width: 640px);
@import url('pequeno.css') screen and (min-width: 256px);
```

Aí nem precisa JavaScript - a imagem vai ser escolhida pelo CSS que será importado de acordo com o tamanho da tela.