# Como descobrir a altura e largura de window SEM JQUERY?

Tags: javascript

Estava me perguntando isso há algum tempo. Tentei de alguma forma descobrir o tamanho de `window` (a janela do navegador) , porém não consegui isso.

Com  jQuery já sei que é simplesmente fazendo:

```
 $(window).height()
```

Mas, e no caso de eu não tiver com jQuery, não sei como fazer isso.

Alguém sabe como pegar a altura da janela (como se faz com `window` no jQuery), porém sem jQuery?

Comment: [Nessa](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7551/capturar-tamanho-da-tela-no-momento-da-requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o#answer-7553) resposta aqui no SO tem exemplos utilizando apenas javascript.

Comment: @bfavaretto, foi mal. Não tinha visto essa pergunta na hora que a redigi

Comment: Não tem problema, acho até que a sua vai ser mais fácil de achar pelo Google

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o `window.inner...`:

```js
var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;
document.write(w + ' width ');
document.write(h + ' height');
```

Comment: Usa `document.write` pra facilitar no snipet

Comment: @WallaceMaxters pra poder completar com Height ou Width, cara tem coisas em js que são tão simples que você pensa, por que estou usando jquery ?

Comment: A questão do jQuery é que você escreve menos código e tem maior compatibilidade com esse código entre os navegadores. Fora isso, acho importante saber funcionalidades básicas como essa. Imagina um teste para programação, onde você está sem jQuery ?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters normalmente quem faz sem jQuery, faz com jQuery. O inverso não. Provavelmente um teste de programação sério nem deixaria usar jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

Obter o tamanho com toolbars/scrollbars

Referencia : [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_outerheight.asp)

```js
var w = window.outerWidth;
var h = window.outerHeight;
 
document.write(w + ' width /' + h + ' height');
```